# Inject a statement after the param block into a PowerShell Here-String

Tags: powershell

I have a here string and I want to inject a statement after the parameter block. The challenge is, I dont know the structure of the Here-String and it should be work for all kinds of Here-Strings (with and without param block).

For example:

```
$scriptBlock = @'

Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$param3
)

Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)

Get-Location
'@

invoke-expression "$scriptBlock"
```

After the param block I want to inject the following statement.

```
Set-Location C:\temp
```

The result should be looks like this:

```
$scriptBlock = @'

Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$param3
)
Set-Location C:\temp

Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)

Get-Location
'@

invoke-expression "$scriptBlock"
```

Comment: What if script block have named sections `begin`/`process`/`end`? Where statement should be injected? Which PowerShell version you target?

Comment: That's a good question the easiest answer is the PowerShell version. Up to version 5.1. It would be useful if the param block contains a begin/process/end section to inject it as the first statement of this section. It sounds not really easy to do it.

Comment: It is not really look hard to me. As you are using PS v3+ you can just parse your script block `[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput` and then navigate AST to find right location to insert your statement.

Comment: Nice with this statement I can extract all comands after the param block.
     ([Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($scriptBlock, $parseErrors,$tokens)).EndBlock.Statements.Extent.Text. Is it possible to inject the stagtment directly into the AST data structure or should I build a new string?

Comment: You don't even need to invoke the parser explicitly, create a scripblock from the string and insert the new statement at the param block end offset

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

### code

```bsh
$scriptcontent = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($scriptblock, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
$paramblock = $scriptcontent.ParamBlock
if ($paramblock) {
    $scriptblock = $scriptblock.Replace($paramblock.Extent.Text, $paramblock.Extent.Text + "`nSet-Location C:\temp;`n")
}
$scriptblock
```

### result

```bsh
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$param2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][switch]$param3
)

Set-Location C:\temp;


Write-Output ('param1: {0}' -f $param1)
Write-Output ('param2: {0}' -f $param2)
Write-Output ('param3: {0}' -f $param3)

Get-Location
```